# Named object parameters in ES6 - How do I check they are provided?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some ES6 code where I am passing in some named parameters of a defined options object like so...

```
    configureMapManager({ mapLocation, configuredWithDataCallback, locationHasChanged })
{
    if (mapLocation) console.log(mapLocation)
}
```

This is a contrived case and the following calls will work fine...

```
configureMapManager({ mapLocation: "BS1 3TQ" })
configureMapManager({})
```

But this will blow up...

```
configureMapManager()
```

...because I cant check that the passed in object is defined (It's not because I called the method without any parameters). How can I do this without having to rewrite this like this (which sucks because then you lose visibility of the allowed parameters within the object)...

```
    configureMapManager(options)
{
    if (options && options.mapLocation) console.log(mapLocation)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use default parameter:

```
function configureMapManager({ mapLocation } = {})
{
  console.log(mapLocation);
}
```

When the function is called without any parameters, `mapLocation` will be undefined:

```
configureMapManager(); // prints: undefined
configureMapManager({ mapLocation: 'data' }); // prints: data
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks @alexmac

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you. Could you accept the answer?

Comment: I was waiting for the time to expire - you have to wait a certain period of time.